# GatsbyJS: If field is empty don't display

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to output a bunch of people's LinkedIn, web or Facebook,  but some of the entries don't have values on a specific field.

How can I do some kind of logic when I'm mapping through the entries to not display that field if it's empty?

Here is what I've tried:

```
 {WpmedarbejderNode.ACFmedarbejder.socials.linkedin !==
                  "null" && (
                  <a href={WpmedarbejderNode.ACFmedarbejder.socials.linkedin}>
                    <MemberSocialIcon
                      src={LinkedIn}
                      alt="Linkedin icon"
                      target="_blank"
                      rel="noopener noreferrer"
                    />
                  </a>
                )}
                {WpmedarbejderNode.ACFmedarbejder.socials.web !== "" && (
                  <a href={WpmedarbejderNode.ACFmedarbejder.socials.web}>
                    <MemberSocialIcon
                      src={Web}
                      alt="Web icon"
                      target="_blank"
                      rel="noopener noreferrer"
                    />
                  </a>
                )}
                {WpmedarbejderNode.ACFmedarbejder.socials.facebook !==
                  "null" && (
                  <a href={WpmedarbejderNode.ACFmedarbejder.socials.facebook}>
                    <MemberSocialIcon
                      src={Facebook}
                      alt="Facebook icon"
                      target="_blank"
                      rel="noopener noreferrer"
                    />
                  </a>
                )}
```

If I test with !== "#" and change the entries to contain # it seems to work. But with !== "null" my code doesn't seem to work. I have also tried making it completely empty like ""

Comment: If you want to check if the `null` value, you should use `!== null` (without double quotes). Anyhow, a common technique is to just write `WpmedarbejderNode.ACFmedarbejder.socials.facebook && (<element />)` (without comparision). Without an explicit comparison, this will only renders the element if `facebook` is true-y (not `null`, not "", and not `undefined` - multiple checks in one)

Comment: Thank you, @BaoHuynhLam! That solved my issue. Please write your comment as answer and I'll mark it as correct answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check against the `null` value, you should use `!== null` (without double quotes). Anyhow, a common technique is to just write:

```
WpmedarbejderNode.ACFmedarbejder.socials.facebook && (<element />)
```

(without comparision)

Without an explicit comparison, this will only render the element if `facebook` is true-y (not `null`, not "", not `undefined`, etc. - multiple checks in one)